# Using PHPMailer on Hostgator (timeout when try to login into SMTP server)

Tags: php, smtp, timeout

**Solved**: The problem was that to use the service through hostgator, for some reason the user must log in using main dsn name and not the SMTP domain name.

I was using the simple PHP `mail()` function to send emails and it was working fine but it didn't require to login into SMPT server. When I moved to `PHPMailer` library I wrote this code to send email but I'm having timeout when when trying to do this login. According to info from hostgator, the SMTP server (with SSL/TSL) is at port `465`. So I wrote:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug  = 3;
$mail->isSMTP();                                       // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'mail.mydomain.com';               // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                              // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'contact@mydomain.com';            // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'pass';                            // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                             // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port       = 465;                               // TCP port to connect to
$mail->setFrom('contact@mydomain.com', 'my name');
$mail->addAddress('....@gmail.com', 'someone');        // Add a recipient

$mail->addReplyTo('contact@mydomain.com', 'my name');
$mail->isHTML(true);                                   // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'subject';
$mail->Body    = 'msg body <b>bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'Corpo alternativo caso o primeiro não seja exibido';

if(!$mail->send())
{
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

But when this php file is called, besides not showing the `echo` I placed before the code, it also waited the 300 seconds to open a modal warning me of the timeout error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check that you are trying to connect to the right host.

Comment: Well, I went to this email's account page and searched for it's configs. There it said `Outgoing Server: mail.mydomain.com SMTP Port: 465` I just changed to "my domain" here but it is the same string. I'm using port 465 because it's through there to send using SSL/TLS

Comment: I think you should have a chat with the service provider, then. The timeout in this circumstance is generally an indication that the connection has been firewalled.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is in your code. You have lines like `$mail->Host       = 'mail.mydomain.com';` Be sure to switch all these out with actual domains. You have to use your `www.com` website domain.

The following is wrong.

```
$mail->Host       = 'mail.mydomain.com';               // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
```

I'm not surprised it won't send. Swap all the values out with real strings that matter to your site.

Answer (score -1):

There are some differences between how PHP's mail() function and the PHP Mailer work. The mail() function sends mail directly from the server where the script is located whereas your hosting provider might be using a separate server to send their emails. Therefore, I'd recommend you to set the SMTP server's FQDN as `$mail->Host` and make sure that the `$mail->SMTPSecure` property should be in fact tls or ssl.

However, there might be a lot of reasons why your code isn't working and unless you post the exact code that you are using (without the password, of course), I doubt that adequate assistance could be provided. It is also recommended to contact the web hosting support.